# Why does this javascript cause a server error on the site I am attempting to automate?

Tags: javascript, automation, server-error

```
var postBackId = 'ctl00$cphContent$ctl00$lnkLoadMoreDoctors';

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function PostBack() {
  do{
    javascript:__doPostBack(postBackId,'');
    console.log('Calling PostBack')
    do{
       await sleep(2000);
       console.log('waiting for eventTarget to revert to null; ID = '+document.getElementById('__EVENTTARGET').value)
    }while(document.getElementById('__EVENTTARGET').value == postBackId);
  }while (document.getElementById('ctl00_cphContent_ctl00_lnkLoadMoreDoctors') != 'null');
}

PostBack();
```

I am simply trying to click a button until all results are shown, but keep getting "Server Error in '/' Application". I do not have a formal javascript education so is there something fundamentally wrong in the code I am trying to execute? It is a pretty consistent error.
It does page a few times but then breaks.

Comment: I dont understand the syntax ` javascript:__doPostBack(postBackId,'');` Did you mean to write ` javascript.__doPostBack(postBackId,'');`?

Comment: JavaScript is run in the client's machine, it doesn't cause server errors.

Comment: I agree with @Flutterish . The syntax is incorrect. It's not an object property or anything like that, so why are you using a colon?

Comment: `javascript:` will parse as a label, which is valid syntax, though almost every time, people just accidentally write them.

Comment: I get the same result using the javascript: or without it, still causes a server runtime error. Could this be happening if the postback was being called and no element with the Id exists on the page anymore?